# Crear un crud utilizando un archivo de texto en c#

Tags: c#, mvc, asp.net-core

Estoy aprendiendo a utilizar asp.net core mvc con c# y lo que quiero realizar es por medio de un formulario enviar la información a un archivo de texto .txt, ya logré enviar dicha información del formulario al .txt, pero lo que requiero hacer es mostrar toda esa información en una tabla en mi vista.

Lo que quiero hacer es un crud, cada registro lo divido asi: "nombre"-"pais"-"comentarios" y llenar la tabla asi:

```
Nombre Pais   Comentario             Acciones
Juan   Mexico Hola soy un comentario Boton Eliminar Boton Editar
Jose   Francia 2do comentario        Boton Eliminar Boton Editar
```

No entiendo muy bien como crear la tabla y llenarla

Adjunto mi código

ComentariosController.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Proyecto3.Models;
using System.IO;
using System;

namespace Proyecto3.Controllers
{
    public class ComentariosController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult LlenarArchivo(Comentarios comentarios)
        {
            string ruta = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "/visitas.txt";
            string textoTXT = "";
            StreamWriter archivo = new StreamWriter(ruta, true);
            archivo.WriteLine(comentarios.Nombre + "-" + comentarios.Pais + "-" + comentarios.ComentariosPersona + "<br>");
            foreach(string linea in System.IO.File.ReadLines(@ruta))
            {
                textoTXT = textoTXT + linea;
            }
            archivo.Close();
            return View(textoTXT);
        }
    }
}
```

Comentarios.cs -> Este es mi modelo

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System;
namespace Proyecto3.Models
{
    public class Comentarios
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Ingrese el nombre")]
        [Display(Name = "Nombre")]
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        public string Nombre { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Seleccione el pais")]
        [Display(Name = "Pais")]
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        public string Pais { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Ingrese su comentario")]
        [Display(Name = "Comentario")]
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        public string ComentariosPersona { get; set; }   
    }
}
```

Esta es mi vista donde tengo mi formulario

```
@model Proyecto3.Models.Comentarios
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Default";
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        <title>Registrar comentarios</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Información de comentarios</h1>
        <form asp-action="LlenarArchivo" method="post">
            <label asp-for="Nombre"></label><br />
            <input asp-for="Nombre" type="text" /><br />
            <label asp-for="Pais"></label><br />
            <select asp-for="Pais">
                <option value="México">México</option>
                <option value="Estados Unidos">Estados Unidos</option>
                <option value="Francia">Francia</option>
                <option value="Colombia">Colombia</option>
                <option value="Brasil">Brasil</option>
            </select><br />
            <label asp-for="ComentariosPersona"></label><br />
            <textarea asp-for="ComentariosPersona"></textarea><br />
            <input type="submit" value="Confirmar" name="confirmar" id="confirmar"/>
        </form>
        <button name="regresar" id="regresar">Regresar</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Esta es la vista donde quiero llenar la información que obtengo de mi txt

```
@model Proyecto3.Models.Comentarios
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "LlenarArchivo";
}

<h1>LlenarArchivo</h1>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        <title>Default</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Comentarios" asp-action="Index">Registrar Comentario</a>
        <a>Listar Comentario</a>
        <p>@Html.DisplayText()</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Pues, por cada línea vas a necesitar un Id, de tal forma que puedas reconocer la línea a editar.

Comment: y como podria hacerlo como crud?, pues debo poder editar y eliminar dicha linea del txt

Comment: Básicamente lees el archivo, recorres cada línea, encuentras "tabs", "comas", "espacios", y vas mapeando a tu clase `Comentarios`. Investiga sobre "StringBuilder" para reemplazar esto: `textoTXT = textoTXT + linea;`

Comment: he estado investigando y quizas con Split serviría, me tiene muy confundido este programa la verdad

Comment: Agrega todo lo que has investigado. Esto genera un aumento del % de obtención de respuesta(s) :)

Comment: muchas gracias! actualizare mi pregunta hasta estar mas cerca, por ahora solo estoy probando

Comment: buen dia, gracias por tus ideas, logré resolver mi duda!

Comment: Excelente :D en la parte inferior existe un bloque para colocar la respuesta, luego que la publiques, espera 24 horas para que la marques como aceptada :D